# Regular expression for address in R

Tags: r, regex, match

I want to take the matching piece that starts with CALLE or CARRERA and ends in the last number found. I can't figure out this regex:

input1: CALLE 15 # 21-32 APARTAMENTO SEGUNDO PISO

output1: CALLE 15 # 21-32

input 2: THIS STRING WON'T MATCH

output 2: THIS STRING WON'T MATCH

And then replace the vector with the matched substring. But if no substring is matched, then leave the original string as it was.

This is what I've tried:

```
df$DirRes2 <- regmatches(df$DirRes2, regexpr("(CALLE.*\\d | CARRERA.*\\d | .*)", df$DirRes2))
```

Comment: Please show where your string starts and ends.  Does the `...` also part of the string?

Comment: I edited it, sorry. The format is originalString ...to... resultString

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Edited again. I think it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

We can do either with `base R`

```
sub(".*((?i)(CALLE|CARRERA).*[0-9])[^0-9]+$", "\\1", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "CALLE 15 # 21-32"        "THIS STRING WON'T MATCH" "Calle 25"
```

Or using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- trimws(str_extract(str1, "(?i)(CALLE|CARRERA)\\s*[0-9]+\\s*#*\\s*[0-9-]*"))
ifelse(is.na(v1), str1, v1)
#[1] "CALLE 15 # 21-32"        "THIS STRING WON'T MATCH" "Calle 25"
```

#### Update

Based on the new pattern provided by the OP in the comments, @Jota's modified version works

```
sub(".*?((?:CALLE|CARRERA).*\\d).*$", "\\1", str2, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) 
#[1] "CALLE 15 # 21-32"        "THIS STRING WON'T MATCH" "Calle 25"  
#[4] "CALLE 18 CARRERA 7"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("CALLE 15 # 21-32 APARTAMENTO SEGUNDO PISO", 
                 "THIS STRING WON'T MATCH", "Calle 25 Something")

str2 <- c(str1,  "CALLE 18 CARRERA 7 CONDOMINIO BELLO")
```

Comment: The # could be missing. The string could be "Calle 25 Something" and it should output "Calle 25"

Comment: It is working fine for most cases, but here's a catch: "CALLE 18 CARRERA 7 CONDOMINIO BELLO" is turning to "CARRERA 7". It should be "CALLE 18 CARRERA 7". Any ideas? Sorry I'm not helping much, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: @AFP_555 Based on the original post, it is not clear whether you had both theses cases occuring in the same string.  Also, their order is not specified.  So, I would say your question was incomplete and was asking others to do a lot of guess work

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I have 500K rows to work with, and it's a little hard to make up a full pattern. That's why I said "start with carrera or calle and end with the last number" checking out random strings I realised "carrera" and "calle" could be present in the same string.

Comment: @akrun, you can make the starting part non-greedy to catch "CALLE 18 CARRERA 7".  Also, because the last number found could be the last character in the string (who knows?), you might adjust for that, too: `".*?((?i)(CALLE|CARRERA).*[0-9]).*$"`

Comment: @Jota Thanks, but when I apply the pattern, it is giving me the full strings for the other cases

Comment: Huh... seems to work for me. I had originally tried with `sub(".*?((?:CALLE|CARRERA).*\\d).*$", "\\1", str1, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)` and that worked for me, too.

Comment: @Jota Sorry, I forgot the `perl=TRUE` earlier.  It works